# Python uses the scapy library to read the wireshark packet capture file and then writes a new file and it cannot be displayed

Tags: python, wireshark, scapy

Use the scapy library in Python to read the file captured by Wireshark and then rewrite it into a new pacp file. After opening it again with Wireshark, some fields cannot be displayed.

This is code written in Python

```
from scapy.all import *

PKT_List = []
pkts = rdpcap("E:\test.pcap")
for pkt in pkts:
    PKT_List.append(pkt)

wrpcap("E:\output.pcap", pkts)
```

The first picture below is the original data packet, and the second picture is the data packet processed by python and then opened with Wireshark.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4xkd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMEw6.png)